# python floodfill Image object

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am floodfill an empty triangle my code is

```
    width, height = copy.size
    center = (int(0.5 * width)), (int(0.5 * height))
    imgC = ImageDraw.floodfill(imgA, center, value = (0, 0, 0, 0))
```

where center is the center of the image which should be in the triangle. Alternatively, I used the Center of Mass as the center but neither worked. It is returning None for some reason. Additionally, imgA which would be changed is not completely floodfilled. Center is

[image]

[image: turned to this]

turns to this. The scale is the same by me I snipped it instead of saving.

Comment: Your original image is apparently anti-aliased (or perhaps was rescaled at some point, which produces much the same effect), so there are pixels of intermediate color along boundaries.  You might get better results by passing the `thresh=` parameter to `ImageDraw.floodfill()`, so that it will paint over pixels that don't exactly match the background color.

Comment: @jasonharper at thresh=750 still returns a rmsd (which I am using to compare the images) difference of 38 to a fully filled octagon.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would have happened. Your flood fill is white, but the fill you are showing is black.

Comment: I don't know why it copied like that. I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function doesn't return anything. Instead it edits the image you provide directly. This is how many of the functions in this package work. If you check `imgA` it should be the result you are looking for. Here are the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill).

> PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill(image, xy, value, border=None, thresh=0)
>
> Fills a bounded region with a given color.
>
> Parameters:    image – **Target image**.

Comment: It's not filling completely and leaving a white inside edge. Do you know why?

Comment: @A_Arnold I'm not sure. It works fine for me. Can you provide an reproducible example?